# (bootstrap, jquery) how to delete all row per pagination ?? & optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, optimization

Performs the task of adding approximately 2000 rows per second to Tabledata:

```
$.each(data.msg, function(count, item) {
    tabledata.push( {"#":"#", 
        "Timestamp":item['Timestamp'], 
        "ID":item['ID'], 
        "ID2":item['ID2'], 
        "DLC":item['DLC'], 
        "Offset":item['Offset'], 
        "Detect":item['Detect'], 
    })
}); 

//append table row

table.rows.add(tabledata).draw();
```

However, as time goes on, too much delay is consumed in rendering and the real-time meaning disappears. Therefore, we are working on initializing the table or deleting rows by a certain period.

```
if ( tableCount%10 == 0 ){
    console.log("remove");
    table.rows($('#packetList tr')).remove().draw(false);
    tableCount = 0;
}
```

However, the problem now is that only one page is deleted from the paginated bootstrap. I have tried to figure out what to do when I want to delete the entire pagination data, but it is difficult to identify a clear example. Please let me know if you know anyone!

p.s. In addition, please let me know if anyone knows the best way to avoid delays in expressing over 2,000 data points per second or more on a web page.

Comment: The configuration environment is a single-page visualization, flask-client, and flask-apiserver. When you upload data from the client, it parses through the api server and processes the visualization work through ajax, jquery, etc. from the client's view page.

Comment: already this tryed:  var rows = table.rows().remove().draw(); & rows('#id tr')